# receive content from other applications with plugin WebIntent

Tags: cordova, android-intent, phonegap-plugins

I want to receive information shared from other applications.

For this I am trying to use The plugin WebIntent : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent

Use Phonegap 2.5.0

In AndroidManifest.xml (To show my application in the section to share)

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

In index.html

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceready, true);

function onDeviceready() {  
    window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
      if(url !== "") {
        // url is the url the intent was launched with
         alert (url);
      }
    });
}
```

var url, the value returned is null.

Plugin src/com/borismus/webintent/WebIntent.java

in res/xml/config.xml

```
</plugins>
....
....
    <plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent" />    
</plugins>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get the uri now! I'm using:

```
window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT, function (url) {
              alert(url);
        }, function() { //Fail
              alert ("error");          
});
```